# Options on EuroStoxx Dividend Futures Data

Tags: futures, historical-data

Does anyone know where I could buy, scrape, or barter this data? Just need closing prices for each available strike going back as far as possible.

Comment: Are you referring this "Euro Stoxx 50"?

Comment: No the Euro Stoxx Dividend Futures...DEDZ1 for example.

Comment: What is the underlying future? You are giving me a bloomberg ticker. I would need the generic ticker for "Euro Stoxx Dividend Futures"

Answer (score 1):

## This is the ticker information for [Eurexchange Index Dividend Futures](https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/product-information)

[image: https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/product-information]

## This is the information for `EURO STOXX 50® Index Dividend Futures (FEXD)`

[image: EURO STOXX 50® Index Dividend Futures (FEXD)]

Enter those into BBG or Reuters to get historical data.

[Source](https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/did/exd/EURO-STOXX-50-Index-Dividend-Futures-946316)

Contact Deutche Borse for historical data

[image: https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/market-data/historical-data]

## 404 on their historical data shop. Email them

[image: hdp@deutsche-boerse.com]
Email `hdp@deutsche-boerse.com`